# PyAudio does not detect my microphone connected via USB audio adapter

Tags: usb, audio, input-device

I am using the latest Raspbian I just downloaded this morning.

I bought this USB audio adapter, https://www.sossolutions.nl/usb-audio-adapter-works-with-raspberry-pi. And then I followed tutorial here, https://learn.adafruit.com/usb-audio-cards-with-a-raspberry-pi/instructions.

The tutorial basically just to add `~/.asoundrc` into this.

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw card 1    
}
ctl.!default {
    type hw card 1
}
```

I checked `alsamixer`, it detects both my microphone and earphone. I use a phone earphone that I usually use to answer call and listen to music with my phone. I attached this mic-earphone into the mic slot of the USB audio adapter.

Then I change `sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` lines into these.

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

However, changing `sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` does not listed as something to do in the Adafruit tutorial I mentioned before.

I have a code to detect pitch and volume with PyAudio from microphone. I tried to run that, but it gives me error of.

```
OSError: [Errrno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
```

The error is in this line.

```
self.mic = pA.open(format=self.FORMAT, channels=self.CHANNELS, rate=self.SAMPLE_RATE, input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=self.PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME)
```

My goal is to have pitch and volume detection using PyAudio via microphone. How can I solve this problem?

EDIT - 1, I have checked via https*//www*onlinemictest*com, my microphone does not work. But it is detected in `alsamixer` as "mic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm updating this answer to include the discussion from the comments and flow more like a troubleshooting guide for future readers.

1. Make sure your USB device is compatible with your microphone. Some devices might not work with 2-in-1 headset/microphones. To eliminate this source of potential problems, use a dedicated microphone.
2. Make sure these lines are in `/etc/asound.conf`:

   ```
   pcm.!default {
       type hw card 1    
   }
   ctl.!default {
       type hw card 1
   }
   ```
3. Use the tutorial's method to test the speaker output and microphone input using software which is known to be good.

   You can use this to test microphone input:

   ```
   arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c1 test.wav
   ```

   And do this to test speaker output:

   ```
   speaker-test -c2 --test=wav -w /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
   ```

   Then try playing the sound you recorded a moment ago:

   ```
   aplay --device=plughw:1,0 test.wav
   ```
4. Assuming those work, run this python script to check which index number you should be using (source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=71062):

   ```
   import pyaudio
   p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
   for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
       dev = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
       print((i,dev['name'],dev['maxInputChannels']))
   ```
5. Then try this snippet of python code to open the microphone:

   ```
   self.mic = pA.open(
       format = self.FORMAT,
       channels = self.CHANNELS, 
       rate = self.SAMPLE_RATE,
       frames_per_buffer = self.PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME,
       input_device_index = self.INPUT_DEVICE_INDEX,
       input = True)
   ```

   Remember define `self.INPUT_DEVICE_INDEX` to be whatever number you discovered when running the previous snippet of python code, or just put the number in its place.
6. If you run into overflow problems and don't want to use exception handling (although it's probably best if you do) you can set `exception_on_overflow = False` in your function call to read the audio data:

   ```
   data = stream.read(chunk, exception_on_overflow = False)
   ```

Best of luck!

Comment: My `/etc/asound.conf` and `~/.asoundrc` are the same.

Comment: Okay, have you tested your configuration using `arecord` specifically? You introduce other potential complications by using a web site to test your microphone. the `arecord` tool is the one indicated by the tutorial, so it's the best one to use to test your ability to record. Then use `speaker-test` as described in my answer to test that it plays. We're trying to use process of elimination to determine the failure.

Comment: My `/etc/asound.conf` and `~/.asoundrc` are the same. `speaker-test -c2` is fine, I can listen through the USB earphone. `arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c1 test.wav` has no error and it generates `test.wav`. But, `speaker-test -c2 --test=wav -w test.wav` returns `Sample rate does not match (44100) for /home/pi/test.wav`

Comment: the first comment was incomplete, I was not aware I cannot do line break.

Comment: I'm sorry, playback command from tutorial is `aplay --device=plughw:1,0 test.wav` I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a snippet of python code to discover which device index you want to be using.

Comment: Hey mate, know I know for sure that the recording works. The problem was I am using the earphone - mic (that is two in one mic + earphone). After I change using dedicated mic I was able to record voice! However the `range(p.get_device_count())` return `(0, 0)`. And I have tried to input `0` or `1` into `input_device_index` and run my PyAudio application again and now it returns `Segmentation vault`. What should I do?

Comment: if you used `self.mic = pA.open(format = self.FORMAT, channels = self.CHANNELS, rate = self.SAMPLE_RATE, frames_per_buffer = self.PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME, input_device_index = 0, input = True)` and got a segfault maybe another device has the mic open? I also noticed a typo in my code (missing comma). I'm fixing it now.

Comment: I always reboot everytime I launch the PyAudio application. Still `Segmentation fault`. `get_device_count()` does not detect anything.

Comment: Alright! It is working mate. So, the solutions were, to use dedicated microphone instead 2 in 1 microphone + earphone, then also start the Python script with `sudo`. At this point, your script works and return all available input. I set my `input_device_index` properly. I start my PyAudio application with `sudo` to detect pitch and volume from mic, it returns `Errno Input overflowed`. At this point I added a flag `exception_on_overflow=False` into `data = stream.read(chunk, exception_on_overflow = False)`. Run again my PyAudio application with `sudo`, then it is working. Thank you mate!

Comment: Congradulations! I updated my answer to include your discoveries.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your `.asoundrc` to

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
  }
}
pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
  }
}
```

You may want to refer to this:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/configure-audio